# How to remove <a> tag while printing in HTML?

Tags: html, css

How to remove the link **a** tag when giving a print command?

```css
.p {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .p {
    display: initial;
  }
  .np {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success np" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
<table id="myHeader" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.</th>
      <th>Student</th>
      <th>Marks</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="http://jainvidhya.co.in/result.php?arn=CB2017AS11Z89010" target="_blank">Anu Bohra</a> <span class="p">Hi</span></td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to add **class** **(np)** in **a** tag, but then it is only showing **Hi**, (which is after  tag)in the second column.

But I want to show the content between opening and closing  tags as well as **Hi**.

But for my code it is showing content + link + Hi

Comment: try `display: inline-block` in the `.p` under print

Comment: Giving class `np` to `a` tag works fine for me. I see `Hi` in the second column when I try to print.

Comment: @casraf I don't want to remove `hi`. I want to remove (http//ja.......) while printing

Comment: @NisargShah But not **Anu Bohra**...

Comment: @PBMusics Isn't that what you want? Can you update the question to show how you want this to be printed?

Comment: @NisargShah Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to hide `a[href]:after` which is showing the link on print, so you could say:

```css
.p {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .p {
    display: initial;
  }
  .np {
    display: none;
  }
  a[href]:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success np" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
<table id="myHeader" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.</th>
      <th>Student</th>
      <th>Marks</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="http://jainvidhya.co.in/result.php?arn=CB2017AS11Z89010" target="_blank">Anu Bohra</a> <span class="p">Hi</span></td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more element after the anchor tag containing the same content. Now you can conditionally show this content while printing by adding class `p` to it:

```
 <span class="p">Anu Bohra</span>
```

```css
.p {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .p {
    display: initial;
  }
  .np {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success np" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
<table id="myHeader" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.</th>
      <th>Student</th>
      <th>Marks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://jainvidhya.co.in/result.php?arn=CB2017AS11Z89010" target="_blank" class="np">Anu Bohra</a>
        <span class="p">Anu Bohra</span>
        <span class="p">Hi</span>
      </td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```